# Problem with PHP on IIS - returning error 500 when large number of data is written in PHP Excel

Tags: php, apache, iis, phpexcel, internal-server-error

I use PHP Excel to export data. Everything works well when I restrict the amount of data to be shown. I get Excel file with different sheets as needed. But when I let full queries, I get error:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. Sheets are of size 40k rows, and 40 columns.

Log gives me this:

> 2020-10-12 07:38:18 10.1.130.10 POST /PBA_PVB4.php - 443 HB\nikola.pejovic 10.1.111.66 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/85.0.4183.121+Safari/537.36 https://tools.hb.co.me/PBA_PVB.php **500 0 3221225477 1799846**

PHP is running on IIS.

I'm new to PHP, and only use it to export data from SQL. If more information is needed, I'll try to provide them.

Comment: This error indicates a problem on the server side, which may be related to permission issues, access issues, database issues. You can go to the web.config file of the deployed application and change its <customerror mode='off'>. This will display a detaield error message about the failure, and you can solve the related problem.